# FormData() . pass multi params in single line

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

my question is so simple I have a react project that uses this syntax:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("token", this.props.token);
data.append("origin", this.props.origin);
....
```

my question is :

is there any way that I can change this appends in to One line or some syntax like this?

```
const data = new FormData([('token', this.props.token), ('origin', this.props.origin)])
```

Comment: No way unless you write a custom wrapper for `FormData`

Comment: if what you say is true, it's so dumb that you can only create 1 one DataForm() and pass dozens of objects with append(). I don't know maybe I'm wrong about this.

Comment: If all the data actually originates from a form, you can pass the form object to the constructor, and it will prepare the whole form data set in one go. If that’s not the case, you could still do this in a loop - over an array containing the parameter/property names as strings, or an object (if parameter name and property name could differ.)

Comment: _if what you say is true.._ You shouldn't take my words on trust. Just [check it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) yourself.

Answer (score 4):

If you want all the items in `props` to be added to `FormData` then you can loop through them and call `formData.append()`,

```
const formData = new FormData();
Object.keys(this.props)
      .forEach(key => formData.append(key, this.props[key])
```

If you want specific keys from `this.props` to add to `FormData`, then you could create an array of all the `key`s and then loop through them:

```
const addToFormData= ["token", "origin"]
const formData = new FormData();

addToFormData.forEach(k => formData.append(k, this.props[k])
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't support by default, you can use third-party package to help you, here a good one https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata

### Example

```
import objectToFormData from "object-to-formdata";

const data = new FormData(objectToFormData({ token: this.props.token, origin: this.props.origin }));
```

### or

```
import objectToFormData from "object-to-formdata";

const { origin, token } = this.props;
const data = new FormData(objectToFormData({ token, origin }));
```

Answer (score 1):

there are no methods available to setting form data in one line

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Methods

but you can pass props like array and loop through it

like :

```
   const keyValuePair=[
      {key:"token",value:this.props.token},
      {key:"origin",value:this.props.origin}
   ]

const data = new FormData();
keyValuePair.map((keyvalue)=>{
  data.append(keyvalue.key,keyvalue.value);
})
```

Comment: This improves nothing over what OP already has TBH. Only thing this creates is an overhead of creating an array manually and then again looping through them. If there are 10 properties, you'd have to create this array with 10 items every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and iterate through each key-value pairs:

```js
const obj = {
  getFormData() {
    const fd = new FormData();
    Object.entries(this.props)
      .forEach( ([key, value]) => fd.append(key, value) );
    // to show they'e added the same way
    fd.append('manual', 'manually set');
    return fd;
  },
  props: {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2',
    key3: 'val3',
    key4: 'val4'
  }
};

console.log(...obj.getFormData());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no type definition for the constant data. If you say data is a FormData and has the proberties token and origin, then you can write it easy in a single line:

```
const FormData data = new FormData(){ token = this.props.token, origin = this.props.origin };
```